# How To Periodically Execute A Function

Tags: c#, timer

How can I execute a C# method every 40 seconds continuously?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Where is this running? On the server?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169288/execute-specified-function-every-x-seconds

Answer (score 5):

You should use the Timer functionality available in .net

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

Here's the code from MSDN, with slight changes.

```
public class Timer1
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {

        // Create a timer with a fourty second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(40000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);    


        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use 
        // KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring 
        // before the method ends. 
        //GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
    // raised. 
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Code that needs repeating every fourty seconds
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been told to not answer with links ;)

Comment: It's far better to use `System.Threading.Timer`, as the one you link too can swallow exceptions.

Comment: I based my answer based on what he's likely to understand, since he can't google "run function every 40 seconds c#" (which is every 2 seconds but close enough) and click on the first link - I assumed threading might be a reach. But @Moo-Juice you're right, it's a much better implementation.

Comment: Should be 40000 and not 4000

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at System.Threading.Timer

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(YourMethod), null, 40000, Timeout.Infinite);
private void YourMethod(object state)
{
    //Magic
    timer.Change(40000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Comment: yes the timer starts after 40 seconds but it has not been asked to start immediately and the timer run´s after every 40seconds try it out timer.Change(40000, Timeout.Infinite) resets the Timer and it will run again ;)

Comment: Ah, didn't know that.  Have changed vote :)  This answer is the more preferable one then, as it uses `System.Threading.Timer`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer  ID="timer" runat="server" Interval="40000"></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       callyourfunction();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest using Quartz.Net for this. You can implement an Service that is scheduled with Quartz.Net. You'll only need to configure your trigger the way you want.