# Run function every 10 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to run function `addFirstSlide` every 10 seconds, but I don't know how and where to do it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addFirstSlide()
    {
        PowerPoint.Slide firstSlide = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[1];
        PowerPoint.Shape textBox2 = firstSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(
        Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 50, 50, 500, 500);
        textBox2.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("firstSlide");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Use [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Google: "run function every 10 seconds in C#" says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169288/execute-specified-function-every-x-seconds

Comment: You should solve with a Timer, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx and http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void addFirstSlide()
    {
        PowerPoint.Slide firstSlide =  Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[1];
        PowerPoint.Shape textBox2 = firstSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(
        Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 50, 50, 500, 500);
        textBox2.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("firstSlide");
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addFirstSlide();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Drop a timer control on to the form and set it's `.Interval` property to 10000 (1 second  = 1000).  Then place your code in the timer's `Tick` event.  Once you enable the timer the code in Tick will run every 10 seconds.

Comment: Good suggestion. Since `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` has no `AutoReset` property, I'd also use a `lock` block to prevent multiple instances from running.