# NAudio - Play an audiofile, wait for 2 seconds, play the audio file again

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm new to NAudio c# but I am currently able to load an audio file and play it in my program. Now, I want to achieve being able to loop this audio file but not until after every 2 second interval. How can I achieve this?

Comment: first. search in google something like this https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+do+something+every+2+seconds+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 then you probably find something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169288/execute-specified-function-every-x-seconds good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For an accurate 2 second wait, I'd create my own `IWaveProvider` that in the `Read` method, read from your source file, then when it finished, returned 2 seconds of silence, and then started reading from the start of the source file again.

For a rough solution, you can just use a timer after the `PlaybackStopped` event fires to kick off a new playback.

Answer (score 0):

Make a timer into your loop's end. Make it sleep for a while.

[Execute specified function every X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169288/execute-specified-function-every-x-seconds)

It has been explained here before.