# How to create a background application?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to create a windows application that runs silently as a background process. The application runs a simple database query that returns a status message. If the status is not 'OK' then display the status message (either as a message box or as a data-grid in a windows form) otherwise continue running the application in the background and run the query again after a set period

My Question is 
1. What project template do I use in VS2010 to create the application above?

Any sample application / example would be of great help.

Comment: If it is updating something in your application, then why does it need to be a separate application? You can do this as a `DispatcherTimer` or a `BackgroundWorker` in your application.

Comment: Trying the push a window into the user's face doesn't work, Windows actively prevents that.  Consider a NotifyIcon.  It can show a balloon.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `Visual C# -> Windows -> Windows Service` template. Here's a link to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having a Windows Service pop up a message box, though.

Comment: @Robaticus: He said he's also using a windows forms app. So the service can send messages to the app, which will then show the popup.

Comment: based on the question, I'm thinking the idea of IPC might be outside of the scope of what they've got experience in implementing. In my experience most of the time developers think they need a service, they actually need something simpler (the same applies to threading).

Comment: I agree, probably a background thread is sufficient for what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try hiding your main form and using something like this.
[Execute an operation every x seconds for y minutes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786672/execute-an-operation-every-x-seconds-for-y-minutes-in-c-sharp)

Or a less ideal solution (depending on your needs) would be to use windows services.